# while making live wall paper for getting weather report facing the following log cat error

Tags: nullpointerexception, live-wallpaper, launching

please go through the following code in http://www.pastie.org/3809101

```
          @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ball = new BallBounces(this);
    ball.activity = this;
    setContentView(ball);
    getGPSdata();
      }
```

this is the main Activity method and project having no errors. why stopping unexpectedly?